# How to avoid duplicate code where only id values change in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, audio-player

I just started learning HTML and HTML5 recently. My site involves different audio players playing different tunes/mp3s. At the moment I have created different id names for each audio player and each play/pause and stop button.

My JavaScript file to play this has unnecessary repetitions of similar code. I guess there is a better way to do this using variables so the code is not repeated with different id names but I am not too familiar with JavaScript.

Here's what a snippet of my JavaScript file looks like.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#play-bt1").click(function() {
    $("#audio-player1")[0].play();
    $("#message").text("Music started");
  })

  $("#pause-bt1").click(function() {
    $("#audio-player1")[0].pause();
    $("#message").text("Music paused");
  })

  $("#stop-bt1").click(function() {
    $("#audio-player1")[0].pause();
    $("#audio-player1")[0].currentTime = 0;
    $("#message").text("Music Stopped");
  })
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#play-bt2").click(function() {
    $("#audio-player2")[0].play();
    $("#message").text("Music started");
  })

  $("#pause-bt2").click(function() {
    $("#audio-player2")[0].pause();
    $("#message").text("Music paused");
  })

  $("#stop-bt2").click(function() {
    $("#audio-player2")[0].pause();
    $("#audio-player2")[0].currentTime = 0;
    $("#message").text("Music Stopped");
  })
})
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#play-bt3").click(function() {
    $("#audio-player3")[0].play();
    $("#message").text("Music started");
  })

  $("#pause-bt3").click(function() {
    $("#audio-player3")[0].pause();
    $("#message").text("Music paused");
  })

  $("#stop-bt3").click(function() {
    $("#audio-player3")[0].pause();
    $("#audio-player3")[0].currentTime = 0;
    $("#message").text("Music Stopped");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="grid_12" id="content">

  <div class="grid_4 alpha">
    <div class="audiobox">
      <audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src="images/electronic beat-monksee.mp3">audio</audio>

      <div class="controlsbox">
        <a id="play-bt">
          <div class="animated_play"></div>
        </a>
        <a id="pause-bt">
          <div class="animated_stop"></div>
        </a>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_4">
    <div class="audiobox">
      <audio id="audio-player1" name="audio-player" src="images/electronic beat-monksee.mp3">audio</audio>

      <div class="controlsbox">
        <a id="play-bt1" href="#">
          <div class="animated_play"></div>
        </a>
        <a id="pause-bt1" href="#">
          <div class="animated_stop"></div>
        </a>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_4 omega">
    <div class="audiobox">
      <audio id="audio-player2" name="audio-player" src="images/beatbox.mp3">audio</audio>

      <div class="controlsbox">
        <a id="play-bt2">
          <div class="animated_play"></div>
        </a>
        <a id="pause-bt2">
          <div class="animated_stop"></div>
        </a>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="grid_4 alpha">
    <div class="audiobox">
      <audio id="audio-player3" name="audio-player" src="images/electronic beat-monksee.mp3">audio</audio>

      <div class="controlsbox">
        <a id="play-bt3">
          <div class="animated_play"></div>
        </a>
        <a id="pause-bt3">
          <div class="animated_stop"></div>
        </a>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_4">
    <div class="audiobox">
      <audio id="audio-player4" name="audio-player" src="images/electronic beat-monksee.mp3">audio</audio>

      <div class="controlsbox">
        <a id="play-bt4">
          <div class="animated_play"></div>
        </a>
        <a id="pause-bt4">
          <div class="animated_stop"></div>
        </a>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_4 omega">
    <div class="audiobox">
      <audio id="audio-player5" name="audio-player" src="images/beatbox.mp3">audio</audio>

      <div class="controlsbox">
        <a id="play-bt5">
          <div class="animated_play"></div>
        </a>
        <a id="pause-bt5">
          <div class="animated_stop"></div>
        </a>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="grid_4 alpha">
    <div class="audiobox">
      <audio id="audio-player6" name="audio-player" src="images/electronic beat-monksee.mp3">audio</audio>

      <div class="controlsbox">
        <a id="play-bt6">
          <div class="animated_play"></div>
        </a>
        <a id="pause-bt6">
          <div class="animated_stop"></div>
        </a>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_4">
    <div class="audiobox">
      <audio id="audio-player7" name="audio-player" src="images/electronic beat-monksee.mp3">audio</audio>

      <div class="controlsbox">
        <a id="play-bt7">
          <div class="animated_play"></div>
        </a>
        <a id="pause-bt7">
          <div class="animated_stop"></div>
        </a>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <feature class="grid_4 omega">
    <div class="audiobox">
      <audio id="audio-player8" name="audio-player" src="images/beatbox.mp3">audio</audio>

      <div class="controlsbox">
        <a id="play-bt8">
          <div class="animated_play"></div>
        </a>
        <a id="pause-bt8">
          <div class="animated_stop"></div>
        </a>


      </div>

    </div>
  </feature>


</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplication of code, you need to introduce a function for the common behavior, with parameters for the variable parts.

Starting from the first part of your example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#play-bt1").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player1")[0].play();
        $("#message").text("Music started");
    })

    $("#pause-bt1").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player1")[0].pause();
        $("#message").text("Music paused");
    })

    $("#stop-bt1").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player1")[0].pause();
        $("#audio-player1")[0].currentTime = 0;
        $("#message").text("Music Stopped");
    })
})
```

We can wrap this building block in a function. The first step is to find a good name for this function. Since the function initializes a player when the document is ready, an explicit name is `initPlayerWhenDocumentReady`. Wrapped in the function, the code becomes:

```
function initPlayerWhenDocumentReady(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#play-bt1").click(function(){
            $("#audio-player1")[0].play();
            $("#message").text("Music started");
        })

        $("#pause-bt1").click(function(){
            $("#audio-player1")[0].pause();
            $("#message").text("Music paused");
        })

        $("#stop-bt1").click(function(){
            $("#audio-player1")[0].pause();
            $("#audio-player1")[0].currentTime = 0;
            $("#message").text("Music Stopped");
        })
    })
}
```

The next step is to extract parameters for the variables parts. One possibility would be to add separate parameters `playerId`, `playButtonId`, `pauseButtonId`, `stopButtonId`.

But on second look, it appears that all the identifiers follow the same format, and only the number at the end changes: `1`, `2`, `3`. Thus, we can just add a single parameter for the number, `playerNumber`:

```
function initPlayerWhenDocumentReady( playerNumber ){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#play-bt"+playerNumber).click(function(){
            $("#audio-player"+playerNumber)[0].play();
            $("#message").text("Music started");
        })

        $("#pause-bt"+playerNumber).click(function(){
            $("#audio-player"+playerNumber)[0].pause();
            $("#message").text("Music paused");
        })

        $("#stop-bt"+playerNumber).click(function(){
            $("#audio-player"+playerNumber)[0].pause();
            $("#audio-player"+playerNumber)[0].currentTime = 0;
            $("#message").text("Music Stopped");
        })
    })
}
```

You can then call this function to initialize the three players:

```
initPlayerWhenDocumentReady( 1 );
initPlayerWhenDocumentReady( 2 );
initPlayerWhenDocumentReady( 3 );
```

The calls to the same function with different values allow to run similar code while reducing duplicate code: only the call is repeated.

And even this limited duplication can be avoided, by using a loop, here defined in a new function, `initPlayers`, which takes the total number of players as parameter:

```
function initPlayers( total ) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++ ) {
        initPlayerWhenDocumentReady( i );
    }
}

initPlayers( 3 );
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I only saw it now. I have since I asked the question in 2013 written completely new code involving just one audio player which changes the src on song select. Your answer looks like it would work :) thank you for your contribution :)